# Error when using std::max in template

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, compiler-errors, max

Could I use an std functions in a template functions?
I have add  and wrote

```
#pragma region BlendFunctions

template <class T> 
T BlendLightenf(T x, T y) 
{ 
    return std::max(x, y); //errors here
} 
template <class T> 
T BlendDarkenf(T x, T y) 
{ 
  return std::min(x, y); //errors here
}
```

And get

```
error C2589: '(' : illegal token on right side of '::'
```

and

```
error C2059: syntax error : '::'
```

right in the one string (x and y are usually `float`).

My defines:

```
#ifdef MAGICLIB_EXPORTS
#define CPPWIN32DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CPPWIN32DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
```

Comment: Just use `std::max` directly, what's the point of this one?

Comment: What headers have you included? Could there be some macros interfering?

Comment: @CatPlusPlus I don't get you. When someone posts large amounts of code you ask them to strip it to the minimum necessary to understand the problem. When they post the minimum, you ask what's the point of doing it like that.

Comment: @PaulManta: The truth is here: http://sscce.org

Comment: @BjörnPollex Yeah, that's the minimum necessary I was talking about.

Comment: Is there any [evil macro](http://ideone.com/vlzM1) in your code ?

Comment: @PaulManta: That would mean that you have taken the exact code posted there, and tried to compile it. Is that correct? In that case, you forgot to `#include <algorithm>`. The idea is that you give us a piece of code that we can throw at our compiler (verbatim, using copy/paste) to reproduce your error. This way we do not have to guess about possible cause that might be locate elsewhere in your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that `max` isn't defined by somebody else.

Sometimes you include a file that defines `max` as something else (most likely `(a > b ? a : b)` or something like that).

If you have one of those files included the preprocessor will break `std::max` by replacing max with its definition (something like this `std::(a > b ? a : b)`) and you get a strange error.

You can add `#undef max` after the offending header and you'll be ok.

Comment: Not just somewhere at the top. It would have to be after the header which defined that macro.

Comment: I have not used any #undef in my project

Answer (score 5):

Are you using VC++?  (The error messages look like it.)  If so, you need
to add a `/DNOMINMAX` to the command line.  (In the GUI, it's under
Configuration Properties→C/C++→Preprocessor→Preprocessor
Definitions.)  Or don't include `<windows.h>` anywhere (but this is hard
to control, since you include files which include other files which 
include...).